# geom_smooth not appearing on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, as.date

I am having a problem where geom_smooth() is not working on my ggplot. Based on previous posts, I have found that because my date variables are character vectors, the geom_smooth() is not working. I am trying to convert my dates from class character to class date but using as.Date results in a class "unknown" for my date variables.

Here is my code to attempt to fix my class type:

```
allmovies <- allmovies %>%
   clean_names() %>%
   select(movie, total_box_office, theatrical_release_release_date, 
     running_time, mpaa, metacritic, sentiment) %>%
   mutate(theatrical_release_release_date = 
   as.character(theatrical_release_release_date)) %>%
   mutate(theatrical_release_release_date = as.Date(theatrical_release_release_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

And here is my code for attempting to plot with geom_smooth(), in case anyone can help me find the error here.

```
ggplotly(tooltip = c("text"),
       ggplot(data = allmovies, aes(x = theatrical_release_release_date, 
          y = total_box_office, color = mpaa, text = movie)) + 
          geom_point() +
          geom_smooth(method=lm) +
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
          labs(color = "MPAA Rating") + 
          ylab("Total Box Office Revenue") +
          xlab("Theatrical Release Date") +
          ggtitle("Total Box Office Revenue Over Time",
                  subtitle = "While revenue generally improved over time, a further analysis shows PG rated movies generated much more revenue over time while PG-13 and R-rated revenue correlations do not appear to be significant.")) %>%
       layout(title = "Total Box Office Revenue Over Time",
              font = font)
```

Finally, here is a sample of my data of the date column:

```
dput(head(allmovies$theatrical_release_release_date))
c("2013-08-23", "2013-03-22", "2012-09-14", "2012-03-16", "2012-02-17", 
"2011-10-14")
```

and here is a small sample of the whole data:

```
structure(list(movie = c("The Frozen Ground", "The Croods", "Stolen", "Seeking Justice", "Ghost Rider: Spirit of Vengeance", "Trespass" ), total_box_office = c(5617460, 573068425, 17967746, 411746, 149217355, 786532), theatrical_release_release_date = structure(c(15940, 15786, 15597, 15415, 15387, 15261), class = "Date"), running_time = c(105, 98, 96, 104, 95, 90), mpaa = c("R", "PG", "R", "R", "PG-13", "R"), metacritic = c(37, 55, 43, 38, 34, 37), sentiment = c(NA, 0.1363636, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Claire. It may be helpful to give some info on the version of R you're using, any packages you have loaded and OS.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data as the problem is likely due to some characteristic of your date column.

Comment: @iod hello! here is what I get when i run "version": platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0                                  
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

I have loaded: 
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(ggrepel)
library(plotly)
library(scales)
library(janitor)

Comment: @Mako212 I edited my post to add a sample! Thanks!

Comment: Samples are better provided as text rather than images. Easiest way is to type in `dput(head(df))` and append to your answer whatever you get there.

Comment: @iod sorry about that, fixed!

Comment: I can't reproduce the error - can you include the actual error text you're getting?

Comment: @iod I'm not getting an actual error, so I can't provide one. However, geom_smooth(method=lm) is not appearing on my plot and I suspect it may be due to the fact that the class for the theatrical_release_release_date variable is "unknown".

Comment: We really don't have enough information to help. The small example of the dates you shared converts to dates just fine for me, with the appropriate class. There could be lots of other reasons the plot isn't working as you expect, but we can't really do an investigating without a full working example that we can run that demonstrates the entire behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @joran  hello -- I've gotten the class to convert, thank you for the feedback. i'm not sure what more info I can provide to help figure out why the geom_smooth() isn't appearing.

Comment: Ideally, you'd provide enough of a data sample that we could run the entire bit of code you shared, including the code that produces the graph.

Comment: @joran the code that produces the graph is in the post. dput(head(allmovies)) is also provided below in response to QAsena's response -- too many characters to post here. Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe `text = movie` is causing `ggplot` to attempt to fit a model to each movie. Try removing that.

Comment: @joran yes thank you that solved it! however, text = movie was allowing plotly to display movie name when the mouse tip hovers over each point. would there be any way to keep that feature without confusing geom_smooth?

Comment: You want the text aesthetic probably only in the `geom_point` layer. When you put them in the top `ggplot()` call, every subsequent layer inherits all those aesthetic mappings. And you don't want them all in `geom_smooth()`.

Comment: @joran you've solved it :) thank you so much for the help and sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the lubridate package:

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
```

Then use the ymd function (check the documentation for dym/ymd order by, `?dmy`):

```
allmovies <- allmovies %>%
   clean_names() %>%
   select(movie, total_box_office, theatrical_release_release_date, 
     running_time, mpaa, metacritic, sentiment) %>%
   mutate(theatrical_release_release_date = 
   as.character(theatrical_release_release_date)) %>%
   mutate(theatrical_release_release_date = ymd(theatrical_release_release_date))
```

If this doesn't work to use `dput` to provide a sample of your data and I'll edit my answer accordingly :).

Comment: Hello! I've provided a sample of the data in the edited version of this post -- unfortunately, trying lubridate with "mutate(theatrical_release_release_date = ymd(theatrical_release_release_date))" still yields an "unknown" class.

Comment: ok try now - I changed it from `dmy` to `ymd` - seems to work with the dput you provided. use `str(allmovies)` to see if the date column is character, factor or date. It should be date now :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked -- do you have any idea, however, why my geom_smooth() does not appear on my plot?

Comment: can you use `dput(head(allmovies))` to give a sample of the whole dataframe and I'll take a look. You only need to copy the console output :)

Comment: structure(list(movie = c("The Frozen Ground", "The Croods", "Stolen", 
"Seeking Justice", "Ghost Rider: Spirit of Vengeance", "Trespass"
), total_box_office = c(5617460, 573068425, 17967746, 411746, 
149217355, 786532), theatrical_release_release_date = structure(c(15940, 
15786, 15597, 15415, 15387, 15261), class = "Date"), running_time = c(105, 
98, 96, 104, 95, 90), mpaa = c("R", "PG", "R", "R", "PG-13", 
"R"), metacritic = c(37, 55, 43, 38, 34, 37), sentiment = c(NA, 
0.1363636, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Thanks, seems like @joran solved this part - I didn't manage!  I think you had the right idea with `as.date` but maybe it should look like this? `allmovies$theatrical_release_release_date <- as.Date(allmovies$theatrical_release_release_date, format='%m/%d')` 
I find lubridate easier :)